# How to concatenate multiple .mat files into one .mat file in python?

Tags: python, scipy, concatenation

I have multiple .mat files with the same columns and same size in them. Since the data is recorded every day, the data varies. I have data for 365 days and I want to concatenate them into one.mat file using python so that I can analyse data for one year at once. How can I do that?

The data is stored in the following ways: Data -> 365 different .mat files

[These are the column names in one of the .mat file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se690.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't concatenate files (except you can append more lines to a text file).  You have to load the files, do the appropriate array concatenate, and write the new array to a new file.  Just to be clear, which `.mat` format is this?  MATLAB, or something else?

Comment: It is MATLAB. How do I do array concatenation? For example, we have pycdf.concatCDF to concat cdf files or pd.concat for .csv files, so do we have something like this for .mat files? or should I make a list x[] and then using np.append, just append one file onto another?

Comment: NO - stay away from `np.append` (it's evil).  Do you know how to load these files?  With `scipy.io.loadmat`?   Load the file, extract the desire array(s), append them to a list.  Then do one `concatenate` at the end to join the list into one array.  Read the `np.concatenate` docs.